# jQuery animation speed increase in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a for loop which prepends an 'li' to the 'ul' list with animation which sits in the for loop, where data is returned from ajax call. However on every ajax call when for loop is executed animation increases in speed so much where it actually disappears, and animation is not visible anymore. Any ideas? I found similar questions but I could not resolve this issue with either of the solutions:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/new_alerts",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    render_date: renderDate
  },
  success: function(result) {
    var list = $('#error-panel-list');
    var timer;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      $("<li class='ann-list-error'> " + result[i] + "</li>").hide().prependTo(list).slideDown(600);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: and how frequent this `ajax` is called , basically i am trying to understand if this `ajax` request is sent on every `keyup` or `keydown` like event ? or there is a for loop on load of the document inside which is this `ajax` call.

Comment: @MasterYoda not with `.prependTo` - that's how you add new html - it's `$("<new html>").prependTo(selector)` http://api.jquery.com/prependto/

Comment: @freedomn-m Fair enough :) learn something new every day. Thanks for the knowledge. Apologies to OP.

Comment: This is with rails btw and ajax gets called every 60 seconds with setInterval. but I think the issue here maybe the for loop with animation, maybe I need to clear that animation somehow after each call. `append_new_alerts();` is the function that executes the ajax call.
`$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  if($("#main-container").length > 0) {
    $("#error-panel").load('/errors').fadeIn(500);
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
      append_new_alerts();
    }, 60000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
});`